# Count the number of occurrences one from few substrings in a T-SQL

Tags: sql, count

Is it possible in T-SQL to count number of occurrence not only for one substring , but for many substrings.

For example I want to count number of occurrences

In pseudocode:
@sub IN (a,e)
COUNT @sub IN 'abdeesf' . It Shiuld return 3.

(calculating occurrences of 'a' and 'e' in 'abdeesf')

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please mention which dbms of what version you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You could try removing those specific characters and then calculating the difference between the original length of the string and what's left.

```
DECLARE @checkValue VARCHAR(50) = 'abdeesf'

SELECT LEN(@checkValue) - LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(@checkValue, 'a', ''), 'e', ''))
```

Comment: Thanks.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Nice thinking. Cheers!